# Rate of systematic code that is a combination of two codes over the same information symbols.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, information-theory, coding-theory

Let $I_k$ be the systematic columns and let two codes be defined over the same systematic  columns $I_k$ as below.

Let $[n_1,k]$ be the first linear systematic code with rate $\frac{k}{n_1} \leq r_1$, with generator matrix

\begin{equation}
G_1 = [I_k | P_1]_{k \times n_1}
\end{equation}

and $[n_2,k]$ be the second linear systematic code over the same $k$ information symbols with rate $\frac{k}{n_2} \leq r_2$. Its generator matrix is

\begin{equation}
G_2 = [I_k | P_2]_{k \times n_2}
\end{equation}

Consider a code with the generator matrix

\begin{equation}
G = G_1 \cup G_2 = [I_k|P_1|P_2]_{k \times n}, \ \ \ where \ \  n=n_1+n_2-k
\end{equation}.

How to obtain a tighter bound on the  rate of this code $\frac{k}{n}$ in terms of both $r_1$ and $r_2 \ ?$

Comment: How is this the union of the two codes? It surely isn't a set-wise union, as $G$ has the same size as both $G_1$ or $G_2$.

Comment: Sorry, its not a union. My intention was to show the structure of generator matrix $G$.  Can the generator matrix be described as union of $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate of the code with generator matrix $[I_k \mid P_1 \mid P_2]_{k\times {(n_1+n_2-k)}}$ is *exactly* $$R = \frac{k}{n_1+n_2-k} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}-1}.$$ So, what kind of "tighter bound" in terms of $r_1$ and $r_2$ are you looking for?

Comment: I was looking for this only.  thank you